# MySQL Returning exact result or a secondary result if there is no exact match

Tags: mysql

I want to return one row if it my value exists, or another row if it doesn't.

I have the following results:

```
ID | Row_To_Check
1  |  1
2  |  2
```

So, if `2` exists in the `Row_To_Check` column, I want to return it (`ID` `2`), otherwise I want to return `ID` `1`.

Can anyone help? this has me stumped.

Comment: Is this always to be a choice between exactly one row and one alternate row, or will it need to support rowsets of varying sizes  for one or both of the matching conditions?

Comment: Always one or another

Comment: given more data like 100 rows, what will be the expectation when searching id 99 but not exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Row_To_Check, x) AS Row_To_Check
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS t
LEFT JOIN mytable ON Row_To_Check = 2
WHERE (x = 1 AND Row_To_Check IS NULL) OR (x = Row_To_Check)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31a07/1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a better solution but this should do the trick

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id, 1 as priority FROM table WHERE Row_To_Check = 2
    UNION
    SELECT id, 2 as priority FROM table WHERE id = 1
) as my_table
ORDER BY priority ASC
LIMIT 1
```